# Stubing class methods in fetch/then/catch with SinonJS

Tags: typescript, fetch, sinon

I'm probably missing something in the way Sinon creates its stubs, but here's the bit of code I'm trying to test (it's TypeScript, but I'm sure it would be the same in ES6 JS):

```
public requestNewUserProfile(authenticationToken: string, callbackUrl?: string): Function {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(this.requestNewUserProfileInit(authenticationToken))

        return fetch(this.buildUserProfileRequest(authenticationToken))
            .then(response => {
                // some error handling
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(user => {
                dispatch(this.requestNewUserProfileSuccess(user))
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch(this.requestNewUserProfileFailure(error.message))
            })
    }
}
```

Since I'm already testing each method called here individually, I'd prefer if I could simply stub them and assert that they've been called. Otherwise, I'll need to mock the data all over again and this in turn results in more brittle tests than I'd like.

I have tried both `sandbox.stub(Class.prototype, 'requestNewUserProfileSuccess')` and `sandbox.stub(classInstance, 'requestNewUserProfileSuccess')` in my tests. The stub works for methods that are inside the anonymous function with the `dispatch` parameter, but as soon as it's called within the `fetch()` call, the mock is ignored and the actual class' method is used, resulting in an error since the result of the fetch call is missing parameters `requestNewUserProfileSuccess()` expects.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? And if so, how would I go about setting this up?